# Rails console can't find Rake, but Bundler installed it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Rake 12.3.1 is in the Gemfile, and installed:

```
/app # bundle install | grep rake
Using rake 12.3.1

/app # grep rake Gemfile.lock
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    rake (12.3.1)

/app # bundle exec gem list | grep rake
rake (12.3.1)
```

Bundler thinks all is well:

```
/app # bundle check
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

A plain `bundle exec ruby` loads it ok:

```
/app # bundle exec ruby -e'require "rake"; p Rake::VERSION'
"12.3.1"
```

But, a Rails console can't find it:

```
/app # bin/rails c
Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

/app # bundle exec bin/rails c
Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show result for `bundle list`?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on but `bundle exec rails c` should work.

Comment: what is the default ruby version displayed in your terminal, make sure when you execute $rails c , same ruby version shows.  Are you using any gemset?

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `bin/rails` file?

Answer (score 14):

Is Spring initialized in your version of rails?  If so, try disabling the Spring rails application preloader:

```
DISABLE_SPRING=true rails c
```

Answer (score 1):

This was inside a Docker container with `BUNDLE_PATH` set to `/gems`. I opened a shell and deleted all the content under `/gems`, bundled again, and now it works.

I'd love to understand what was happening, but now I get to move on.